# integral with absolute value on exponential

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, manifolds, change-of-variable

\begin{align}
\int\int{\exp(-k|\vec x_1-\vec x_2|)d^2\vec x_1d^2\vec x_2}
\end{align}
where $k>0$ of course.

The notation $d^n q_k$ to indicate integral over the $n$ coordinates of a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I tried using polar coordinates transformation ,
\begin{align}
 \int d^2 x= \int_0^\infty \!\! x ~dx ~\int _0^{2\pi} d\theta
\end{align}
But this does not simplify the integral.

How to perform the integration of the integral above by changing the variable to the center of mass and relative coordinate,as below, 
\begin{align}
u&=(x_2+x_1)\\
v&=\frac{1}{2}(x_2-x_1)
\end{align}

Comment: The center of mass coordinates are $(x_1 + x_2)/2$ and $x_2-x_1$. To do the change of variables, find the Jacobian determinant of the transform.

Comment: can you elaborate your view , I'm not sure how to do it for this case.